# Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve SSH Connection ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, ip, router

Hi everyone I'm using an Ubuntu server and I want to allow the access through any network in the world.

1. I configured the static ip address.
2. I have mapped the port 22-22 in the router configuration
3. I'm using the router ip address to perform an SSH connection

> ssh user@router_ip -v

And here's the response:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/my-mac-user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/my-mac-user/.colima/ssh_config
debug1: /Users/my-mac-user/.ssh/config line 15: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to router_ip [router_ip] port 22.
```

Comment: `Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve` seems like an issue on the mac client side. Are you actually trying to use FIDO/U2F authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after connecting to a new network that had a different local gateway address than the previous network. I had a firewall rule that only allowed connections from a specific range of ip addresses like 192.168.0.0/24, but the new local network was a different ip range e.g. 10.0.0.1/16. Take a look at your firewall rules of `ALLOW` & `DROP` on the host, see if your local ip addresses are within the `ALLOW` range rule and not in the `DROP` rule.